# Uses of [comparative-review]

Tags: discussion, tags, comparative-review

I recently discovered this [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review) tag while reading some PE questions. It says:

> This tag is used for questions which present a problem and multiple solutions, where the asker wishes to know which solution is best (and why).

- Aren't many programming problems usually have multiple solutions?
- Say the asker does not state that he wishes to know which solution is best (he might think his solution is best), but reviewers found his current solution and code to be absolutely disgusting. As reviewer, isn't it better to recommend a better solution right away to improve the code?
- [This question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74982/project-euler-12-first-triangle-number-with-more-than-500-divisors) has the tag, but the asker didn't really ask for other solutions (basing this on the tag description), he asked for an explanation/review on his current solution. It's already jamalized so using the tag there is considered fine by the site. But how is that?

But if that's really what comparative-review means, why not all questions comparative-reviewed?
Am I missing something? How to use this tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your observations are keen, but your understanding of the tag is misplaced.

The [comparative-review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/comparative-review) is supposed to be used when the question contains two (or more) alternate implementations of the same code, and the question is "which one is better, and why?"

So, your questions are:

- *Aren't many programming problems usually have multiple solutions?*

  Yes, problems normally have multiple solutions, but, are they presented (as working code) in the Code Review question?
- *Say the asker does not state that he wishes to know which solution is best*

  Then the tag is not appropriate for the question....
- *[This question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74982/project-euler-12-first-triangle-number-with-more-than-500-divisors) has the tag, but the asker didn't really ask for other solutions (basing this on the tag description)*

  That question is a poor example for the tag's use. It is not a comparative review. I am removing the tag.

For a better example, see: [Which FizzBuzz is better, and why?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60145/31503)

Answer (score 3):

> [This question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74982/project-euler-12-first-triangle-number-with-more-than-500-divisors) has the tag, but the asker didn't really ask for other solutions (basing this on the tag description), he asked for an explanation/review on his current solution.

To be precise, he asked for **why** one of his two solutions was better than the other solution.  Admittedly, he wasn't asking which was better, as he already knew that.  He did want to understand **why** the one was better in **comparison** to the other.

- Presented a problem.
- Multiple solutions.
- Wanted to know why one solution performed a lot better than another.

The only thing that question was missing was a desire to know which was better.  It certainly wanted a review of one implementation in comparison to another.